# Kafka haven't been configured to work in either Raft or Zookeper mode. Please make sure at least one of the modes is configured

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to run Kafka with help of docker compose on my local Ubuntu

I see the following error:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Starting kafka-producer_kafka_1 ... done
Attaching to kafka-producer_kafka_1
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.38 INFO  ==> 
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.38 INFO  ==> Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.38 INFO  ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.38 INFO  ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.38 INFO  ==> 
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.39 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.46 ERROR ==> Kafka haven't been configured to work in either Raft or Zookeper mode. Please make sure at least one of the modes is configured.
kafka_1  | kafka 16:06:40.49 WARN  ==> Kafka has been configured with a PLAINTEXT listener, this setting is not recommended for production environments.
```

My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9094:9094"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT

volumes:
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

What should I fix?

Comment: The bitnami kafka container repo has the exact compose file you need. Why change it? https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using latest version of Kafka. It is capable to run either using KRAFT mode or to depend on ZooKeeper.

KRAFT mode configuration options are provided [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#apache-kafka-kraft-mode-configuration) for bitnami containers.
Zookeeper mod configurations are provided [here](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#apache-kafka-zookeeper-mode-configuration).

You have to add them under `environment` section of your yaml file as per your preference.